# How to select max value from a temporary table whose field is unnamed

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm writing a PL/SQL function that needs to get dates from a few different tables and return the most recent one. My approach has been this:

- Create a temporary table to hold the dates:

  `CREATE TYPE t_dates IS TABLE OF DATE;
  /`
- Create a few local variables:

  `l_date DATE;
  l_dates t_dates := t_dates();
  l_idx INTEGER := 0;
  l_output_date DATE;`
- Then select into a variable each date I'm interested in, and add it to the temporary table:

  `SELECT it.date
    INTO l_date
    FROM interesting_table it
   WHERE it.id = 1
  ;`

  `l_dates.extend;
  l_idx := l_idx + 1;
  l_dates(l_idx) := l_date;`
- After the temporary table has been populated, now I just want to select the max value from it. How do I do that? Something like...

  `SELECT max(*)
    INTO l_output_date
    FROM l_dates
  ;`

  `RETURN l_output_date;`

But I'm not sure I can reference my temporary table like that, nor how to find the max of a column that is unnamed.

Edit: When I test the above, I get an error: `PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression` related to the line where I have `SELECT max(*)`. However, I don't believe that this is my only error, because if I change the last block to:

```
SELECT *
  INTO l_output_date
  FROM l_dates
 WHERE rownum = 1
;
```

which, just for testing, should select the first date in the temp table, then the error becomes `PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`, which indicates to me that I can't refer to my temp table in this manner.

I have since learned from the comments that I should have `max(column_value)` rather than `max(*)`, but using this, I still get the `table or view does not exist` error.

Comment: What happened when you tested what you just wrote? You did test it before posting here, didn't you? (If not, why not?)

Comment: @mathguy, I'm getting an error: `PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression` related to the line where I have `SELECT max(*)`.

Comment: Perfect - that should be part of the question! Now: when you create a nested table like that, the column name (by default) is `column_value`. And, `MAX()` - unlike `COUNT()` - can't be used with `*`. Try `max(column_value)` instead.

Comment: Then... `select max(column_value) from TABLE(l_dates)`, right? Missing the `TABLE()` operator?

Comment: @mathguy question updated...

Comment: ...but I think you have already solved it! `TABLE()` operator!  
Yes indeed, just tested it, and it's working successfully

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to select from the nested tables, like you have tried.
You may have to use a logic to find the maximum value

```
l_idx := l_idx + 1;
l_dates(l_idx) := l_date;
if(l_date > l_dates(l_idx-1) OR l_idx =1) THEN 
   max_date :=l_date;
End if;
```

For your case, Rather than fetching a list of dates then getting the max date,  you can find the max date in your query itself

```
SELECT max(it.date)
  INTO l_date
  FROM interesting_table it
 WHERE it.id = 1
;
```